# Inducing artificial network latency in Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, performance, hyper-v, performance-monitoring

I want to do some testing on how will system performance degrade with various changes in network throughput and latency. I am using Hyper-V for virtualization.

Is there a way I can artificially limit throughput and artificially induce latency between guests?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

WanEM (http://wanem.sourceforge.net/) or Shunra (http://www.shunra.com/).  Shunra's solutions are pretty much the defacto standard for network impairment and emulation.   WanEm os open source and gets the job done for a particular link.  Don't accept the default virtual machine model deployment for WanEm for the clock needs higher precision than what a virtual machine can offer for effective and consistent network impairment: Install it on a physical machine and adjust your routing to go through the WanEm host.

Answer (score 0):

I've used TMNetSim with excellent results:

http://www.tmurgent.com/tools.aspx